# Redirect StatusCode with message to Error Page

Tags: asp.net-core, error-handling, .net-7.0

Recently found a strange behavior. I am not able to redirect to default error message when I use a status code with a message.
I am using .Net Core (Net 7.0)

**program.cs**
[image]

**HomeController.cs**
[image]

**Output**
[image]

**The goal is a redirect to this page**:
[image]

Any ideas will appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried as you mentioned and found that if you return an ObjectResult with ErrorMessage,it won't trigger the error handler,The handler only handle  NotFoundResult\StatueCodeResult....

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

For example,if I try with  `return StatusCode(500);` it could hit`"/Home/Error"` with the middleware `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error");`

[image]

Try throw an Excption  with message directly

and try as below in Error Controller:

```
var exceptionHandlerPathFeature =HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
            var errmessage = exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Error.Message;
            var vm = new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier, ErrorMessage = errmessage };
            return View(vm);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @RuikaiFeng, thank you for understanding the issue and explanation. I found another fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

UseExceptionHandler middleware is use to catch exception, log it and re-execute it with given path. Re-execution will hit the HomeController's Error method and it will return the Error view from shared folder of Views.

From your code on line no 22 you are returning StatusCodeResult and it is not any exception. Idea is UseExceptionHandler is use to catch error.

To redirect to particular page on status code, you can use UseStatusCodePages middleware.

You can do following:

1. Add middleware (Add after UseHttpRedirection)

[image: Add midleware]

2. Add related action method in HomeController

[image: Add related action method]

3. Add views in shared or home folder.

[image]

Comment: Hi Kunal, thanks for the feedback. It unfortunately didn't work. Did you test it using .Net 7? I think this issue is a bug.

Comment: Yes. You can downland this zip https://ufile.io/6lj0sda9  and check the code. Specifically check home controller's index method.  (Note: I am using this ufile first time, I didn't know and I just check initially it download some .exe but on second time it download the 7z file)

Comment: Hi @Kunal thank you for taking the time but this wasn't the solution or explanation I needed.